# Как правильно реализовать функцию класса?

Tags: php, ооп

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать разные функции для одного класса.

Задача: Есть несколько сайтов, с которых берется информация, на некоторых сайтах есть API, на некоторых нет. Я хотел создать класс сайта, реализовать в нем функции обращения к сайту, извлечения нужной информации из ответа (структура у всех сайтов разная) и возврат буквально пары значений. Все входные данные для получения ответа с сайта абсолютно однотипные, но для извлечения нужных данных из ответа применяются различные функции.

По сути только одна функция будет отличаться во всех объектах класса.

Как это можно реализовать? Можете дать нужные ссылки?

Comment: Создаете класс в котором есть все функции кроме одной, отличающейся. Создаете кучу классов наследников от данного в которых прописаны разные варианты этой отличающейся функции.

Comment: книга Котеров php 7